# I am trying to mount the external drive on linux servers using samba client getting wrong fs type error

Tags: samba, nas, samba4

Mounting on Linux

```
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.7 (Maipo)"
```

External drive name:

```
\\nav02001XXXXX10-XXXs01.aud01.XXXXXXXX.com\XXXXXXX$
```

Using below command :

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=XXXXXXX,domain=au.XXXXX.com,uid=XXX,gid=XXX,port=XXX '\\nav02001adds10-XXXs01.aud01.XXXXXXXX.com\XXXXXXX$' /opt/XXXXXX/NAS/


mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on \\nav02001adds10-XXXs01.aud01.XXXXXXXX.com\XXXXXXX$
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       (for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might
       need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program)

   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail or so.
```

Comment: Try using forward slashes with the server/sharename.

Comment: have tried that as well getting the same error

Comment: So what did you find in syslog?

Comment: Is it actually a samba share?

Comment: What does `smbclient -L nav02001XXXXX10-XXXs01.aud01.XXXXXXXX.com` show?

Comment: this is the response for the above command : so what do I need to do ? Do I need to enable anything from my end ?


read_socket_with_timeout: timeout read. read error = Connection reset by peer.
Receiving SMB: Server stopped responding
protocol negotiation failed